# Are eigenvector continuous?

Tags: calculus, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Lets consider a matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{d\times d}$, where $d=2$ or $3$,
$\ A$ has entries $a_{ij}(x)$, where $a_{ij}\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Also, $A$ is positive definite. Given the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$ are the values that satisfy
$$Av_i = \lambda_i v_i,$$
where $v_i$ is the corresponding eigenvector. I think the derivative 
$$\frac{\mathrm d\lambda_i}{\mathrm dx}$$
exists, since $\lambda_i$ are the roots of a polynomial with coefficients that are again multivariate polynomials in $a_{ij}$, therefore being continuous in $\lambda_i$.

What I was wondering was if the eigenvectors $v_i$ are as well. Usually the eigenvectors are all vectors which satisfy 
$$ (A-\lambda_iI)v_i=0,$$
but the matrix $(A-\lambda_iI)$ is singular, so I don't know whether the eigenvectors are still continuous.

Comment: $\lambda_i$ is a function of $a_{ij}$, which is a function of $x$.

Comment: It's confusing that you denote both the eigenvectors and the position variable by $x$. I would use the notation $v_i$ for the eigenvectors.

Comment: Good point, will fix it now

Comment: Also, you should define an ordering of the eigenvalues, otherwise there is no reason that $\lambda_i$ would refer to the "same" eigenvalue for different $x$.

Comment: I don't see why this is important I want to know about all eigenvectors, given that I know $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$. $v_i$ is only dependent on the corresponding eigenvalue, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: what eigenvectors are you talking about? what if an eigenspace has dimension greater than 1?

Comment: I think that either my question is vague, or the problem is more difficult than I think it is. I am talking about the eigenvectors of $A$, which I know is in $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$. $A$ is positive definite, but may have double eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s$ denote $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, and let 
$$
M = \pmatrix{s & -s \\ s & s}
$$
be rotation by $\pi/4$.

Let 
$$
X(u) = \pmatrix{u & 0 \\ 0 & 1}.
$$
Then for $u \ne 1$, the matrix 
$$
M X(u) M^t
$$
has eigenvectors in the directions $\pmatrix{\pm s\\s}$ (the "diagonal directions") while the matrix $X(u)$ has eigenvectors in the directions $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\1}$ (the "axial directions").

Now consider
$$
H(t) = \begin{cases}
M X(1 + t^4) M^t & t < 0 \\
X(1 + t^4) & t \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

Then $H$ has the form required by your problem (although my variable is $t$ rather than $x$), but for $t > 0$, the eigenvectors are axial, and for $t < 0$, the eigenvectors are diagonal, and no choice of eigenvectors for $t = 0$, where the matrix is the identity and *every* vector is an eigenvector, will make either eigenvector a continuous (let alone differentiable) function of $t$.

(I admit I haven't written out every detail here, and maybe I need to put in something like $\exp(-\frac{1}{t^2})$ instead of $t^4$ to make everything smooth....but I don't think so).

Comment: NB: You *could* make the "eigenvectors" be continuous functions of $t$ if you were (a) willing to let them not have unit magnitude, and (b) let them be zero vectors for the identity. But the "eigenvectors are nonzero" thing is an important part of the definition.

Comment: I have some more information about $A$ then I could say in my question, I actually know a lot. This answer gives me more then enough information to put the pieces together. Thank you!